# BizTalk 2010 Send FTPS - when is client certificate hash "thumbprint" needed?

Tags: ftp, ssl-certificate, biztalk, biztalk-2010, ftps

Based on this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6963840-af6d-42cb-a1e9-8c2224c93d49/biztalk-2010-ftp-adapter-ssl-send-port?forum=biztalkgeneral), it's very unclear if a certificate is needed or not.  The most important quote I got out of that post is this:

> "I reached out to MS BizTalk support and they asked me not to use the
>   certificate and just use FTP over SSL without certificate. We also
>   changed the ftp firewall mode to passive and allocate storage to no."

Also consulted this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d6963840-af6d-42cb-a1e9-8c2224c93d49/biztalk-2010-ftp-adapter-ssl-send-port?forum=biztalkgeneral).
If FileZilla client can connect and send a file to a customer/vendor without a local certificate, then why would BizTalk need one in an FTP SendPort?

And secondly, if it is not needed, in what circumstances would you use it on an FTP SendPort.

It's my understanding that the certificate is some certificate related to the BizTalk host account's personal store on the BizTalk machine, and not the thumbprint of the customer/vendor we are communicating with.

For BT2013 this is [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa546802.aspx)'s mysterious definition:

> Specify the SHA1 hash of the client certificate that must be used in
>   the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) negotiation.
>
> Based on this hash, the client certificate is picked up from the
>   personal store of the user account under which the BizTalk host
>   instance is running.

This statement gives no guidance as to when it is needed or desired. 
This is the [other good blog](http://screenone.blogspot.com/2012/11/biztalk-2010-and-ftps.html) on the subject, but also implied cert is needed, in contradiction to Microsoft support in early link.

Comment: NOTE: another lesson learned is that you must Restart BizTalk's FTP Host Instance each time you make a change on the SendPort.  The theory I read somewhere is that the "ftp connection isn't closed between transfers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the client certificate, when the FTPS server requires authentication with the client certificate. And you do not use it, when the server does not require that (what is a way more common).

FileZilla does not support the client certificates at all. If you are able to connect with FileZilla, your FTPS server does not require authentication with the client certificate. So you just leave the respective field in BizTalk blank.

Comment: Maybe found an exception - would you agree with this statement from my colleague?  For Biztalk to accept a self-signed  cert we need to load the cert into the trusted cert store other wise when Biztalk gets the SSL cert it cannot verify it.

Comment: Yes, your colleague is correct.  You need to add the public key of the self signed SSL cert into your trusted cert store (for the user that the host runs under).

Comment: But in that case, even if we add cert to store, do we need the thumbprint of our cert? We are a side issue is that the self-signed cert is not matching the site name that is slowing down a resolution.

Comment: Sorry, one area of confusion.  When I said certificate, I was actually referring to the our cert whose thumbprint is entered in the BizTalk's "Client Certificate Hash" field in the SendPort. I think now that both Martin and @Dijkgraaf were referring to the customers certificate, which we have not installed in our local cert store.

Comment: @NealWalters Yes, in this scenario you aren't using a Client Certificate to authenticate.  Just the SSL certificate on the FTP server to encrypt the traffic. So only if the SSL cert is self signed on the FTP server do you need to add it to your cert store in this scenario.

Comment: The "Client Certificate Hash" is to select a *client* certificate for authentication. Not to accept an untrusted *server* certificate. To trust (otherwise untrusted, e.g. self-signed) server certificate, you have to add it to certificate store. Not sure though if that helps in case the certificate is issued for a different host, as that not about the trust to the certificate, but about it's misuse for another host.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - so what would I ask the customer/vendor to know "when the FTPS server requires authentication with the client certificate".  Obviously there are different FTP programs they use, but would this be a parm they typically set.  We finally got a connection working after many many hours; turns out they a cert that didn't match URL with domain name in Cert.  BizTalk wouldn't allow that at all. Now with correct CA-signed cert and matching URL/Domain, and with thumbprint, we got it working.  For this case, fails without thumbprint.

Comment: If they require client certificate, it's up to them to tell you and set up one as part of the account creating. If you want to ask explicitly, ask simply *"Does your server require authentication with the client certificate?"*. It's likely they won't know, what would mean, they do not.